# how to return back to controller action from asp.net page added in mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have application with Home controller and Index Action .I added an Asp.net page in mvc project and i want that on following event control goes to the following action.How is it possible.

```
 protected void ImgBack_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

Comment: what is happening currently??

Comment: A void method doesn't return anything, that code must give an error. It should be `ActionResult` instead of `void`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
protected void ImgBack_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/home/index");
}
```

Edit: Edited to better answer the question